# Cleaning Pandas df with varying column types and values

Tags: python, pandas

Good evening,

My pandas df (python) looks like this:

[image]

I would like to do the following:

1. Create a date column using col 0 and col 1 -> 11 Apr
2. Join the strings that is between the date and first numeric value and
   label it as Description 1.
3. Extract the first numeric value and label it as Amount 1
4. Extract the second numeric value and label it as Amount 2
5. Join the strings that are after the numeric value and label it as Description 2.

In the end, my pandas df would have:

- **Date**: 11 Apr
- **Description 1**: abcd efgh ijklmnop
- **Amount 1**: 425.85 (12.34 is a just a placeholder amount in the illustration)
- **Amount 2**: 365.12 (12.34 is a just a placeholder amount in the illustration)
- **Description 2**: ab cdefgh ijklm

How do I effectively clean this df to achieve my desire outcome?

Thank you!

***Sample Data***:

```
{0: {20: '11', 21: '11', 22: '14', 23: '16', 24: '18', 25: '19', 26: '19'}, 1: {20: 'Apr', 21: 'Apr', 22: 'Apr', 23: 'Apr', 24: 'Apr', 25: 'Apr', 26: 'Apr'}, 2: {20: 'ACTNOWQUICK', 21: 'Cash', 22: 'ACTNOWQUICK', 23: 'ACTNOWQUICK', 24: 'Inward', 25: 'Cash', 26: 'Inward'}, 3: {20: '1234.56', 21: 'WithdrawalATM', 22: '76.53', 23: '1236.00', 24: 'DR', 25: 'WithdrawalATM', 26: 'CR'}, 4: {20: '1234.98', 21: '50.00', 22: '653.24', 23: '1234.78', 24: 'FUTHN', 25: '70.00', 26: 'YJHK'}, 5: {20: 'HYE912630964589376', 21: '1111.22', 22: 'HYE91234234589376', 23: 'HYE91263234234234376', 24: '60.00', 25: '222.22', 26: '33333.33'}, 6: {20: 'PLUTO', 21: '23523455', 22: 'WiN', 23: 'YOU', 24: '11.11', 25: '123123123', 26: '18.18'}, 7: {20: 'THEATRE', 21: None, 22: 'OTHR', 23: 'TECHY', 24: 'WOL', 25: None, 26: 'OTHER'}, 8: {20: 'OTHER', 21: None, 22: 'JOHNKLING', 23: 'BRO', 24: 'E54E236A58', 25: None, 26: 'Other'}, 9: {20: 'WUN', 21: None, 22: None, 23: 'OTHER', 24: 'FFF', 25: None, 26: 'PFFS'}, 10: {20: 'Cool', 21: None, 22: None, 23: '123123123523452', 24: 'UEJH', 25: None, 26: '(JUPITER)'}, 11: {20: 'Beans', 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: 'EVEREST'}, 12: {20: 'KIng', 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: '236272345235'}, 13: {20: None, 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: None}, 14: {20: None, 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: None}, 15: {20: None, 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: None}, 16: {20: None, 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: None}}
```

Comment: Please share the data as dictionary

Comment: Have edited to provide a sample data. Thank you.

Comment: So you could have multiple descriptions in one row right? and the number of description is variable right?

Comment: That's right. So I wanna merge them into 2 fields. Description 1 and Description 2. Description 1 will take all the strings between the date to the 1st numerical value (numbers with decimal) and Description 2 will take all the strings After 2nd numerical value (numbers with decimal)

Comment: So are there exactly gonna be two numerical values? or the number of numerical values you have, you want to create those many description column.

Comment: Yes, exactly 2 numerical values as amount 1 and amount 2. And they can be identified as the only numbers with decimal. Other fields may have numbers but if they do not have demical, they are just either description 1 or 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246821/discussion-between-madwolf-and-himanshu-poddar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can join the columns on `not None` values, and then regex can be applied using `pd.extract` with `expand = True` option to get the required groups.

```
dict_ = {0: {20: '11', 21: '11', 22: '14', 23: '16', 24: '18', 25: '19', 26: '19'}, 1: {20: 'Apr', 21: 'Apr', 22: 'Apr', 23: 'Apr', 24: 'Apr', 25: 'Apr', 26: 'Apr'}, 2: {20: 'ACTNOWQUICK', 21: 'Cash', 22: 'ACTNOWQUICK', 23: 'ACTNOWQUICK', 24: 'Inward', 25: 'Cash', 26: 'Inward'}, 3: {20: '1234.56', 21: 'WithdrawalATM', 22: '76.53', 23: '1236.00', 24: 'DR', 25: 'WithdrawalATM', 26: 'CR'}, 4: {20: '1234.98', 21: '50.00', 22: '653.24', 23: '1234.78', 24: 'FUTHN', 25: '70.00', 26: 'YJHK'}, 5: {20: 'HYE912630964589376', 21: '1111.22', 22: 'HYE91234234589376', 23: 'HYE91263234234234376', 24: '60.00', 25: '222.22', 26: '33333.33'}, 6: {20: 'PLUTO', 21: '23523455', 22: 'WiN', 23: 'YOU', 24: '11.11', 25: '123123123', 26: '18.18'}, 7: {20: 'THEATRE', 21: None, 22: 'OTHR', 23: 'TECHY', 24: 'WOL', 25: None, 26: 'OTHER'}, 8: {20: 'OTHER', 21: None, 22: 'JOHNKLING', 23: 'BRO', 24: 'E54E236A58', 25: None, 26: 'Other'}, 9: {20: 'WUN', 21: None, 22: None, 23: 'OTHER', 24: 'FFF', 25: None, 26: 'PFFS'}, 10: {20: 'Cool', 21: None, 22: None, 23: '123123123523452', 24: 'UEJH', 25: None, 26: '(JUPITER)'}, 11: {20: 'Beans', 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: 'EVEREST'}, 12: {20: 'KIng', 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: '236272345235'}, 13: {20: None, 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: None}, 14: {20: None, 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: None}, 15: {20: None, 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: None}, 16: {20: None, 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: None}}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_)
df[['Decription1', 'Amount1', 'Amount2', 'Description2']] = df[df.columns[~df.columns.isin([0,1])]].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1).str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]*) ([0-9]*[,.][0-9]*).* ([0-9]*[,.][0-9]*)(.*)', expand=True)
```

##### Output

This gives us the expected output

[image]

Comment: thank you. Will try this and keep you posted!

Comment: Thank you for the elegant code. It gave me an idea and also new ways on working on this, and through this, I learnt something new too! Really appreciate it!